# MySQL print values of variables inside a function

Tags: mysql, function

I have a MySQL function.  Inside this function I want to print the values of variables when it runs.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION
  `updateCompanyName`(companyName varchar(200)) RETURNS varchar(200)
  CHARSET latin1 BEGIN

  declare modifiedCompanyName varchar(200); 
  DECLARE keywordToRemove varchar(200); 

  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM company_remove_keywords;

  select regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z 0-9]', "",companyName) into modifiedCompanyName;

  OPEN cur1;  
    read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cur1 INTO keywordToRemove;
      select keywordToRemove;

      select replace_ci(modifiedCompanyName,
             concat(" ",keywordToRemove," ")," ") 
             into modifiedCompanyName;
      select replace_ci(modifiedCompanyName,
             concat(" ",keywordToRemove),"")
             into modifiedCompanyName;
    END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1; 
  return modifiedCompanyName; 
END
```

What is the best way to print the values: `keywordToRemove` and `modifiedCompanyName`?

Comment: You can't. However, what you can do is use MySQL's SIGNAL to force an error and then read the error output.

Comment: You're missing a continue handler.

Comment: For debugging, I sometimes define a sproc with the same body (minus any `RETURN` statements) and then output debugging state with `SELECT`.

Comment: I guess you could write debugging info to a (temporary?) table and read it from there later on. Don't have experience in this, though, so I won't write this as an answer until someone confirms that this actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create table (or temporary table) to store debug information, and insert values you need to this table.

Also, you can easy debug stored procedures/functions/triggers with GUI tool - [Debugger for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html) (try trial version).